# Outlook calendar import to sharepoint problem

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, outlook, exchange-server, office365

I have a problem with  Outlook calendar and Sharepoint. I want to send my Outlook Calendar to Calendar in Sharepoint and this calendar will be available for other people.

When I create new calendar in Sharepoint, I click Search but with no results.

What is "URL program address OWA" and "URL services Web Exchange"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show your Exchange calendar within SharePoint you can use the Outlook Web App web parts. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232199.aspx

If you would like to actually sync your calendar to a SharePoint calendar, there are some third party applications for this.